# Explore docker volumes on windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, volumes

My working env. is: Windows 10 Pro Up-to-Date (13/01/2020) and Docker 19.03.5

Trying to map a volume to a folder location from dockers to windows FS is not working as read on this discussion:

https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/issues/152

So as suggested, I use the docker managed volumes to persists my data. It actually works but what I would like to know if there is a way to explore these volumes that are handles directly by docker.

By now I think that the file where everythins is stored is:

C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\vm-data\DockerDesktop.vhdx

Which I tried to open with wome vhdx reader without success. I think it may be possible to mount it but apparently I have not rights to do so. Maybe I'm even wrong on the file name.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks on advance!!